# How can I change the values in my multi index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  multi index dataframe. I'm trying to change some of the inner values in the index.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
                  2019    2020
                  1   2    1  2
 L0   L1      L2
 Blue Red     X  100 150  200 250
 Blue Yellow  Y  100 150  200 250
 Blue Green   Z  100 150  200 250
```

I'm trying to change all mentions of "Green" in the index into "Yellow"
From rooting around on StackOverflow, I found a similar thing, but it doesn't seem to work. I've written:

```
df.index.set_levels(["Green", "Yellow"],level="L1",inplace=True)
df.set_labels([0, 1],level=1,inplace=True)
```

But it returns an error:

"On level 1, code max (5) >= length of level (2). NOTE: this index is in an inconsistent state"

I'm still learning Python and I don't really understand this error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `set_levels()` or `set_labels` methods, try to use `rename()`.

Check for the oficial documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, Henrique, When I write df.rename(index={"Green" : "Yellow"}, level = "L1")...nothing happens. Does it matter that the labels aren't actually colours but numbers? Thank you!